# Backbone.js TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone.js. I'm trying to define a model change event in the view but am getting the following javascript error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

If I take out the initialize from the view, it displays the text without error.

Do I have the correct basic structure for a Backbone app?
What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function rdy() 
{
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name:   'Alex',
            age:    33,
            }
        });

    person = new Person();

    var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#content',
      initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);  //ERROR HERE <----------
        }, 
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("Aargh Hello " + person.get('name'));
        return this;
        }
    });

  var NavigationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "defaultRoute"
            },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.view = new ContentView({});          
        return this;
        },
    defaultRoute: function (actions) {
        this.view.render();
        }
  });
  var navigationRouter = new NavigationRouter;
  Backbone.history.start();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a model into the view. Like:

```
// Pass in the person you made earlier. Alternatively, you could use
// new Person() instead of creating the person separately
this.view = new ContentView({ model: person });
```

Then your render function should also be using `this.model`

You could also put a check in the view, but if the view is going to rely on there being a `Person` model, you should probably let it fail like that so you don't forget.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked fine and I changed the render function. I tried:  this.view = new ContentView({model: new Person()}); as an the alternative way to do it. But that didn't respond to change event.